# How do I enable verbose GC on Android?

Tags: java, android, debugging, garbage-collection

I'm debugging a problem in which lots of GC is happening (i.e. many GC_CONCURRENT, WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC, and GC_FOR_ALLOC messages are appearing in logcat) for mysterious reasons. A small sampling from the log:

```
08-13 08:59:12.051  25878-25932/com.myco.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 393K, 6% free 9740K/10344K, paused 11ms, total 12ms
08-13 08:59:12.067  25878-25882/com.myco.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 375K, 6% free 9750K/10344K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 16ms
08-13 08:59:12.067  25878-25932/com.myco.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms
08-13 08:59:12.082  25878-25932/com.myco.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 380K, 6% free 9744K/10344K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
08-13 08:59:12.106  25878-25932/com.myco.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 375K, 6% free 9740K/10344K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
08-13 08:59:12.137  25878-25882/com.myco.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 379K, 6% free 9745K/10344K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 23ms
08-13 08:59:12.145  25878-25932/com.myco.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
08-13 08:59:12.168  25878-25932/com.myco.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 369K, 6% free 9743K/10344K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
08-13 08:59:12.192  25878-25932/com.myco.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 380K, 6% free 9740K/10344K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
08-13 08:59:12.207  25878-25932/com.myco.myapp D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 375K, 6% free 9743K/10344K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
```

I want to know what objects are being created in such volumes that GC has to be run so often. I'd like to see what objects are being destroyed during GC.

On a desktop system, I believe that enabling `-verbose:gc` in the JVM would do the trick. Is it possible to enable verbose GC on Android? How can I see what GC is destroying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to track allocations in Android monitor to see what's going on. See https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html for details about debugging your app's allocations.

[image]

Also check out this video from a past Google I/O about Android Memory Management: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk